# How can I use persistStore with Redux-Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I have the following:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { searchReducer } from "./search/searchSlice"
import { userReducer } from "./user/userSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    search: searchReducer,
    user: userReducer
  }
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

I need to persist only the `user` reducer. How can I do it since there isn't any definition of a 'user' reducer outside the `configureStore` function? What should be in the place in the `"???"` below?

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer({
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: [???]
}, ???)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Comment: You have two `???`.  The first should be your reducer path string.  The second one should be the root reducers unless the API has changed.  Beware you might want to define some transforms to get the hydration right if things look funny.

Comment: you mean the first ??? should be ./user/userSlice?

Answer (score 1):

The `persistReducer` function takes two arguments, a persist configuration object and a reducer to persist.

The reducer you would like to persist needs to be created and passed to the store when it is created. You can't persist specific reducers after the fact.

Example:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { searchReducer } from "./search/searchSlice";
import { userReducer } from "./user/userSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["user"] // <-- name root state to allow, e.g. state.user
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  search: searchReducer,
  user: userReducer, // <-- state.user
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

You can also persist ***just*** the `userReducer` if you like. See [Nested Persists](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist?tab=readme-ov-file#nested-persists).

Example:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { searchReducer } from "./search/searchSlice";
import { userReducer } from "./user/userSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "user",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  search: searchReducer,
  user: persistedUserReducer,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  search: searchReducer,
  user: userReducer
});

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer(rootReducer)
})

const persistedReducer = (reducers) => persistReducer({
    key: "root",
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ['user']
}, reducers);
```